# Как в отчете JasperReports выводить последнюю страницу с другим шаблоном?

Tags: jasperreports, java

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в JasperReports выводить последнюю страницу, которая должна быть с другим шаблоном (в моем случае другая структура страницы, на которой выводятся суммарные данные).

Т.е. отчет состоит, допустим, из 30 страниц данных + последняя страница другого содержания (на которой суммарная информация со всего отчета).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В объявлении атрибутов отчета

```
<jasperReport 
    xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports 
    http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
    name="Diagnostic_Result_For_2_Stages" 
    language="groovy" 
    pageWidth="595" 
    pageHeight="842" 
    columnWidth="555" 
    leftMargin="20" 
    rightMargin="20" 
    topMargin="20" 
    bottomMargin="20" 
    isSummaryNewPage="true"
>
```

есть атрибут **isSummaryNewPage**, который говорит, что суммарную информацию надо выводить на новой странице.

А в блоке отчета суммарной информации может быть какая угодно структура.

Comment: @Антон Мухин Это ответ на вопрос или уточнение вопроса?

Comment: Это ответ на вопрос.

Comment: И правильно JasperReports, а не JasperReport. Sorry